# Get MongoDB items matching date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, meteor

I am trying to get a count on posted item from `meteor-mongo` matching date periods.

I inserted my posts dates as such.

```
posts
  submitted: new Date()
```

the dates in the database have the following format.

```
yyyy-mm-dd 16:16:34.317Z // I do not understand the last part (what format it is)
```

I have tried this to get match the `date of today` from the `submitted` field

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var dd = currentDate.getDate();
var mm = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = currentDate.getFullYear();
var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

Posts.find({submitted: today}).count()
```

However, the last part is returning `0`.

Is it because the last hh,mm,ss part of today is missing? If so, how can I tell `meteor-mongo`to ignore the time part of date so that I can return that count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like to deal with JS date objects formats, and i guess you either (*I do not understand the last part (what format it is)*)

Give a try to [momentjs package](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment), the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/) its pretty clear.

So on the insert you can have something like.

```
var today = moment().format(''MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // April 3rd 2015, 12:17:06 pm
Posts.insert({subbmited:today})
```

and do a simple find like this.

```
var endQuery = today..add('days', 3).calendar(); // just an example.
Posts.find({submitted: {$gt: today,$lt:endQuery}})
```

Here thanks to @Larry Maccherone point we are using [$gte](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) (grater than) and [$lt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) (less than), so this works like *find me post between the post submitted day and the post submitted dat + 3 days (like you ask managing ranges)*

Comment: Ah I was using momentJS for other things, but I didnt use it for this. Didn't even think about it! Thanks Ethaan

Comment: I see that this answer is accepted but I worry. You seem to be recommending that he store his answer only in day granularity as a string. That may very well work, but I generally recommend that you store all events in millisecond granularity but when you want to pull out a particular day, you provide a range query specifying the start and end date-time for the day. In MongoDB, you'd use $gte and $lt.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone that was a quickly example, the example code its just some kind of demonstration, the real point of this answer was pointing him to moments package, and to show what he can do.

Comment: @Ethaan, I think the key to the best answer is not moment.js but rather that you specify an inequality like Curtis' answer. Throwing away information (like the time that the post was submitted) upon insert will accomplish his stated goal, but there is a way to keep that detail and still accomplish it by using an inequality comparison ($gte/$lt), IMHO.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone just made a little update to the answer

Comment: Are these valid? `var todayStart = moment().format('MM DD YYYY, 00:00:00');`  `var todayEnd = moment().format('MM DD YYYY, 23:59:59');`    `var thisMonthStart = moment().format('MM 01 YYYY, 00:00:00');`  `var thisMonthEnd = moment().format('MM 31 YYYY, 23:59:59');` and then using. `Posts.find({submitted: {$gte: todayStart, $lt: todayEnd}}).count();`  and `Posts.find({submitted: {$gte: thisMonthStart, $lt: thisMonthEnd}}).count();`

Comment: @Ethan, you are getting there. However, if you are going to store in strings and use inequalities, you'll need to use a string format like the ISO-8601 which starts with the highest order value (year) and works its way down to the lowest. Example: `2015-03-04T12:34:56.789Z`

Comment: I've been meaning to update this to use moment.js in addition to tzTime, but here is a writeup I did a while back with my recommendations on how best to work with dates: https://gist.github.com/lmaccherone/5371881

Comment: @SangYooKim, you should use a format like ISO-8601 when storing strings and using inequalities.

Comment: @Ethaan is the above comment I left here valid? Idk why its partially working.. So I cant seem to figure out if its good or bad. It ignores year if I do MM 01 YYYY MM 31 YYYY

Comment: @SangYooKim what do you get on the `count()`?

Comment: @Ethaan I get the correct count but not completely correct. For example, if I do `MM 01 YYYY 00:00:00` start and `MM 31 YYYY 23:59:59` end to get posts from `this month`, I get the correct number. Except it ignore the year. So the posts from this month disregarding the year returns.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing your submitted date in MongoDB with both time and timezone information. Performing a direct comparison of your `currentDate` with the `submitted` date in Mongo will never be true, since your `currentDate` does not contain time information.

Also you are using a `String` data type to query the date, which also will not work since you need to use a `Date` data type. Something like this will work for you:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
Posts.find({submitted: {$gt: today}})
```

Which will return all the posts with a date greater than midnight of today's date.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Curtis. But I am planning on dealing with more formats, and the below answer gave me a more flexible solution!

Comment: @Curtis, I think you are on the right track, but you'd probably want to specify a $gte and a $lt to pull back a particular day. Granted if all he ever wants is today and there are no future dates in the database, your answer would give the desired results. Using $gte and $lt provides a more general purpose answer for all the events in any day. You can even specify a timezone for your "day" with the way I'm proposing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
posts.find({"submitted": /.*today*/})
```

Comment: What does the /.*today*/ do?